# I'm trying to configure HRD for IC7300 but cannot connect / detect frequency

Tags: software, icom, computer-control

Got the firmware updated.

Got the Driver updated.

Got the software updated.

Went through instructions several times.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the COM port is correct? If you’re connecting locally (you didn’t say), it’s probably not correct; if you’re really using some Internet-controlled software, your router may need additional configuring to let the traffic through.

Comment: Are you trying to connect the computer to a radio in the same room, or a radio connected remotely over the internet?  Your problem sounds like a classic serial communication failure, and the advice we might give would be quite different depending on how you're trying to connect the computer to the radio.

Comment: I've verified the port. They (HRD) told me to set the baud rate to Auto but that also did not help. It's all local. No remote. USB directly to radio.

Comment: Crap. It just started working for no reason that I can discern. I've saved the settings. I was trying to get it to a place where I could use WSJT-X also.